# Is there any way to access non-file fields in a multipart/form-data POST before parsing the file?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express

I'm writing some middleware to handle an image upload for my app (written in Node.js). I'm using the multiparty module and things have been going great, but I've encountered a problem. I'm trying to access some fields that have been included with the request before I parse the form (so that I can perform some validation). From the examples that I've found, fields included with a multipart/form-data POST are only available after the form has been parsed. Is there a way to get access to non-file fields included in the file upload request before parsing the file?

The best way that I can think to do this is by including some customer headers. Would this be the best way to go about this? I want to avoid the expense of uploading the file if the validation on the field(s) fails.

I'm using the [Loopback](http://loopback.io) framework which is built on top of Express if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance for your help and happy Thanksgiving!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the way to do this is to put your non-file fields before your file fields. At least HTML forms submit their fields in the order they are in in the DOM.

I'm not sure what module loopback uses for parsing forms, but busboy for example passes fields to you in the order it sees them in the request (not saving anything to disk or buffering entire files in memory).